# app:itemBackground attribute doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

I'm trying to create a custom selector for the `NavigationView`, but it has no effect. This is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/state_list_drawer_background" />
```

And the selector is `state_list_drawer_background.xml`, here's the code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Checked state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- This is the default background color -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_normal" />
</selector>
```

I just can see the transparent selector, instead of the custom selector. Then, I found a limitation for `NavigationView` as documented **[here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)**:

> The itemBackground attribute for the NavigationView does not handle the checked state of the item correctly: somehow either all items are highlighted or none of them are. This makes this attribute basically unusable for most apps.

But, on some developers are able to set the custom selector, for example [tTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tagsoft.ttorrent.pro) app on Dark Theme. I wonder how they can do it!

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"`. I know this is not what you want, but mahbe it helps as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Please fill a bug report on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list.

I bet tTorrent does not use `NavigationView` to implement the main menu.
I don't either, I find it easier and more flexible to create my own custom layout.

Comment: Marked as fixed in 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'. I tried and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the color in selector like this:
inside:drawable/item_selector.xml

```
<item android:color="#8C9EFF" android:state_checked="true" />
<!-- This is the default text color -->
<item android:color="#FFFFFF" />
```